# Separate string by first two whitespaces and comma, PHP

Tags: php, parsing

I have a long set of numbers and description followed by a comma that I need to parse into 3 fields, for example:

```
001 009 Intestinal Infectious Diseases,010 018 Tuberculosis,020 027 Zoonotic Bacterial Diseases,030 041 Other Bacterial Diseases,
```

I need to insert the data before each comma into 3 fields in my database, start, end and description. 2 examples would be:

```
start: 001; end: 009; Description: Intestinal Infectious Diseases
start: 010; end: 018; Description: Tuberculosis
```

so basically, the first space ends the start digits, second space ends the end digits, and the comma ends the description.

I am unsure as to how I would write this out so I can store each record... any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could do this with a regex. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php for how to use it.

Comment: Use `preg_match_all` to get all the matches.

Comment: Regular expressions might be an overkill here when explode can work.

Comment: Explode can't identify the exact pattern the OP wants. "the first space ends the start digits, second space ends the end digits, and the comma ends the description". This can be done with one regex, `(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(.*?),`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
<?php
$string = '001 009 Intestinal Infectious Diseases,010 018 Tuberculosis,020 027 Zoonotic Bacterial Diseases,030 041 Other Bacterial Diseases,';
preg_match_all('~(\d+)\s(\d+)\s(.*?),~', $string, $matches);
for($i =0; $i < count($matches); $i++) {
    echo 'First integer: ' . $matches[1][$i] .
        'Second integer: ' . $matches[2][$i] .
        'Description: ' . $matches[3][$i] . "\n";
}
```

This regex is looking for one whitespace between the values. If it should be at least one whitespace character add a `+`. The `\d+` is at least one number and as many continuos numbers until a white space. The `.*?` is everything until the first comma.

Output:

> First integer: 001Second integer: 009Description: Intestinal Infectious Diseases
>   First integer: 010Second integer: 018Description: Tuberculosis
>   First integer: 020Second integer: 027Description: Zoonotic Bacterial Diseases
>   First integer: 030Second integer: 041Description: Other Bacterial Diseases

Answer (score -1):

Use explode on a comma to first seperate it into an array that contains the numbers and description.

Then, for each string from above, use explode again, but on a space, with a limit of 3.

http://php.net/explode

Sorry. Typing on a small mobile phone, so not easy to give you coding exampled.